# Scala XML literal - Boolean vs String

Tags: scala, scala-xml

I ran into this behavior which surprised me.  Essentially, if I create "the same" XML `Elem` from two different XML literals, they fail to equal one another.  The unique thing here is that I am using a `Boolean` in one and a `String` in the other.

```
scala> import scala.xml._
import scala.xml._

scala> val t: Boolean = true
t: Boolean = true

scala> val fromBoolean: Elem = <b>{t}</b>
fromBoolean: scala.xml.Elem = <b>true</b>

scala> val fromString = <b>true</b>
fromString: scala.xml.Elem = <b>true</b>

scala> fromString == fromBoolean
res0: Boolean = false
```

Is this the expected behavior?

It seems that Scala is storing the underlying type and a Boolean doesn't strictly equal a String.

Is this correct interpretation, and can anyone explain what exactly is going on here?  I couldn't find a way to inspect the underlying type within the two nodes.  If I look at the children they just appear to be `Node`s.

```
scala> fromString.child(0)
res1: scala.xml.Node = true

scala> fromBoolean.child(0)
res2: scala.xml.Node = true
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your interpretation is correct. The child of `fromString` is `scala.xml.Text`, which extends `scala.xml.Atom[String]`:

```
scala> fromString.child(0).getClass.getName
res1: String = scala.xml.Text

scala> fromString.child(0).asInstanceOf[xml.Atom[_]].data.getClass.getName
res2: String = java.lang.String
```

And the child of `fromBoolean` is `scala.xml.Atom[Boolean]`:

```
scala> fromBoolean.child(0).getClass.getName
res3: String = scala.xml.Atom

scala> fromBoolean.child(0).asInstanceOf[xml.Atom[_]].data.getClass.getName
res4: String = java.lang.Boolean
```

So the `data` of `fromString`'s child `Atom` has type `String`, and the `data` of `fromBoolean`'s `Atom` has type `Boolean`. The equality implementation of `Atom` (`scala.xml.Atom#strict_==`) just compares the `data` directly, and so the `String` and the `Boolean` compare unequal.

I'm not sure what's the purpose of distinguishing the types of `Atom` data. It seems to me that `Atom` should compare `toString` values of its data anyway. So this behaviour might be a bug.

As a workaround, I can advise to convert the atom values to `String` explicitly. The equality works in that case:

```
scala> <b>{true.toString}</b> == <b>true</b>
res5: Boolean = true
```

---

Scala xml comparison does have more quirks though:

```
scala> <foo:b xmlns:foo="foo"/> == <foo:b xmlns:foo="bar"/> 
res6: Boolean = true

scala> <b>{"<"}</b> == <b>&lt;</b>
res7: Boolean = false

scala> <b>></b> == <b>&gt;</b>
res8: Boolean = false
```

So it may be worth it to try implementing comparison manually.